# Shrinked frames with hyperrefs in Beamer have displaced hyperlinks

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I needed to shrink a frame containing long text with hyperlinks. However it appears that the hyperlinks in the generated PDF are displaced from the text.
Below is a simple demonstrator:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\let\raggedright=\RaggedRight
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=20]{Test shrinked frame with hyperlinks}
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is the first item with \href{https://wikipedia.org}{Wikipedia hyperlink}
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item This is the middle item with \href{https://github.com/josephwright/beamer}{Beamer hyperlink}
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item Here we have another item
    \item This is the last item with \href{https://stackoverflow.com}{Stackoverflow hyperlink}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you compile it with:

```
pdflatex slides.tex
```

You'll get a PDF file, where only the last hyperlink is correctly placed over the blue text (Stackoverflow hyperlink). The first and the second hyperlinks are moved up and right from their correct position.

That significantly affects a possibility to use "shrink" to "compress" slides with hyperlinks.

Is it possible to cure that problem?

Comment: no, not really. Annotations are placed absolutely on a page. Beside this: if you have to shrink a frame it normally means that you have way to much text on it.